# What's the definition of a "collection"?

Tags: set-theory

I cannot seem to find a formal definition for the following.

What's a "collection" in the context of set theory?

Answer (score 7):

"Collections" have no formal existence in set theory. The word is **deliberately left without a technical meaning**, such that it is available for speaking about our *intuitive* non-rigorous idea about, erm, *collections* of things -- without implying that the collection we're talking about satisfies the formal conditions for being considered a "set" or "class", both of which are often technical terms.